# How do I find the display size using Carbon

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

How do I adjust the height and width returned by CGDisplayBounds by the menu bar height and the dock height (or width if it attached to the side)?

I need to do this using only Carbon calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside that you really ought to be moving away from Carbon already…

Use [the `HIWindowGetAvailablePositioningBounds` function](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Window_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/HIWindowGetAvailablePositioningBounds).

If you need it to work in 64-bit, then you're just going to have to [use Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScreen/visibleFrame).